# How to set Select Element width to span element using jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
<td class="ADDDLFFForm2" colspan="5">
    <div>
        <select style="width: 91px; display: none;">
            <span id="" class="selectboxit selectboxit-enabled selectboxit-btn"  style="width: 95px;">
                <span class="selectboxit-option-icon-container" style="width: 95px;">
                    <i id=""></i>
                </span>
                <span id="" class="selectboxit-text" unselectable="on" data-val="1" aria-live="polite" style="max-width: 79px;">
                    Deutsch
                </span>
                <span id="" class="selectboxit-arrow-container" unselectable="on">
                    <i id="" class="selectboxit-arrow selectboxit-default-arrow" unselectable="on"></i>
                </span>
            </span>
            <ul class="selectboxit-options selectboxit-list" tabindex="-1" role="listbox" aria-hidden="true" style="min-width: 109px;">
                <li data-id="0" data-val="1" data-disabled="false" class="selectboxit-option selectboxit-option-first selectboxit-selected" data-icon="/WikiNotificationMails - Copy/Base/Untitled/Image.ashx?" role="option">
                    <a class="selectboxit-option-anchor">
                        <span class="selectboxit-option-icon-container" style="width: 95px;">
                            <i></i>
                        </span>
```

I want set the `select` element width to be the same as `span class="selectboxit selectboxit-enabled selectboxit-btn"` width. How can I do this?

Comment: Your question is not clear. See [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to ask properly, so that you can get help soon.

Comment: Your HTML is incorrect; you cannot have any element inside a `select` other than `option` or `optgroup`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var width = $(".selectboxit-enabled").css("width"); //First get the width of span with class selectboxit-enabled

$("select").css("width",width); // then set that width to select
```

Comment: I think the OP wants this the other way around.

Comment: i think he want to set width of span to the selectbox..do you think so?

Comment: bacause accroding to his previos content it seem that he want to set selectbox width to the span..but now he has changes the content of question

Comment: He wants to set the width of the `select`.